# Add suffix to comma-separated strings in bash ecosystem

Tags: linux, bash, sed, gnu

Is there a way of transforming a comma-delimited variable to add a suffix to each token using standard gnu tools? e.g.

```
VARIABLE=`aaa,bbb,ccc`
suffix=`-foo`
Expected output = `aaa-foo,bbb-foo,ccc-foo`
```

Additionally, if I have only one token, the transformation should behave in the same way

e.g. `aaa` -> `aaa-foo`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
echo "aaa,bbb,ccc" | sed -E 's/([^,]+)/\1-foo/g'
```

It makes groups of characters that are not "," and then append `-foo` on it

With variables:

```
suffix="-foo"; VARIABLE="aaa,bbb,ccc"; echo ${VARIABLE} | sed -E "s/([^,]+)/\1${suffix}/g"
```

Comment: This looks like the cleanest to me

Comment: Yep, it is a very `sed`y problem

Comment: If `suffix` has a slash it will confuse `sed`.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo $VARIBLE | tr "," "\n" | awk '{print $1"-foo"}' | paste -sd "," -
```

#### explanation:

put each token on single line

```
tr "," "\n"
```

append "-foo" to each token

```
awk '{print $1"-foo"}'
```

join back up with the original comma

```
paste -sd "," -
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
answer = `echo $VARIABLE | sed "s/,/-foo,/g" | sed "s/$/-foo/"`
```

If you need to  have the suffix as a variable then try:

```
answer = `echo $VARIABLE | sed "s/,/${suffix},/g" | sed "s/$/${suffix}/"`
```

I don't have access to a Unix box at the moment to prove this works.

Comment: When assigning variables in shell (except for csh), you can't have spaces around the equals sign, and it's recommended to stick with `$(..)` notation instead of backquotes. Also, why two sed expressions? Sed can take multiple `-e` options, or you can combine commands into a single script with a semicolon. Also, note that your second option will also fail if `$suffix` contains a forward slash.

Answer (score 0):

The following:

```
s="aaa,bbb,ccc"
IFS=,
a=( $s )
mapfile -t b < <(printf '%s-foo\n' "${a[@]}")
```

should give us:

```
$ declare -p b
declare -a b=([0]="aaa-foo" [1]="bbb-foo" [2]="ccc-foo")
```

From there, if you can reconstruct the original format in a number of ways...

```
IFS=, eval 'JOINED="${b[*]}"'
```

Or if you don't like using `eval`, perhaps:

```
d=""; o=""
for x in "${b[@]}"; do
  printf -v o '%s%s%s' "$o" "$d" "$x"
  d=,
done
```

... which will put the complete modified string in `$o`.

Answer (score 0):

With bash Parameter Expansion

```
var='aaa,bbb,ccc';[ -n "$var" ] && printf "%s\n" "${var//,/-foo,}-foo"
```